FLutter when i use a streambuilder to display data from firebase it just says true when on phone
I wish to display a list of events store in firebase firestore and it works well on android emulator and web but when i try it on my real phone it instead just returns the text true to the page. I dont know why because both the emulator and real machine are android. If anyone might know why this happens please help. all of this is in dart of course
class _events_page_state extends State<events_page> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Events").snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Stack(
                children: [
                  ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return ListTile(
                            titleAlignment: ListTileTitleAlignment.center,
                            title: Card(
                              clipBehavior: Clip.hardEdge,
                              child: InkWell(
                                splashColor: Colors.blue.withAlpha(30),
                                child: SizedBox(
                                  width: 350,
                                  height: 200,
                                  child: Stack(
                                    children: [
                                      Positioned(
                                        top: 10,
                                        left: 10,
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                          children: [
                                            Text(
                                              "${snapshot.data!.docs[index]["name"]}",
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                                            ),
                                            Text(
                                              "${snapshot.data!.docs[index]["description"]}",
                                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Positioned(
                                        bottom: 10,
                                        left: 10,
                                        child: Text(
                                          "${snapshot.data!.docs[index]["date"]}",
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Positioned(
                                        bottom: 10,
                                        right: 10,
                                        child: IconButton.outlined(
                                          onPressed: favorite(),
                                          icon: Icon(
                                            Icons.star,
                                            color: Colors.yellow[700],
                                            size: 24.0,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ));
                      }),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 30,
                    right: 30,
                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        setState(() {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (context) => const add_event_form_page(),
                            ),
                          );
                        });
                      },
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      hoverColor: Colors.blue,
                      focusColor: Colors.blue[300],
                      child: const Icon(
                        Icons.add,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              );
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Center(child: Text("${snapshot.hasError.toString()}"));
            } else {
              return Center(child: Text("an unexpected error has occured"));
            }
          } else {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }}


Please attach your error snapshot for more clarity.

StreamBuilder(         stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Events").snapshots(),  DO NOT BUILD THE STREAM in the stream parameter of the StreamBuilder.  Lift it out to an outer scope.

You're getting true because of some error in the streamBuilder, and executing the line
return Center(child: Text("${snapshot.hasError.toString()}"));

probably some firebase connection issue

thanks bro i totally forgot that firebase had that test period thing rule so i completely forgot that it just denied my read an write requests. thanks for making me check the connection to firebase, i am stupid. thx bro
